# how to get file from xooplate.com using php

Tags: php, curl, download, file-get-contents

i see  http://xooplate.com/templates/download/13693 return a file.
i have using

```
$ch = curl_init("http://xooplate.com/templates/download/13693");
$fp = fopen("example_homepage.zip", "w");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);


function get_include_contents($filename) {
    if (is_file($filename)) {
        ob_start();
        include $filename;
        $contents = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        return $contents;
    }
    return false;
}
$string = get_include_contents('http://xooplate.com/templates/download/13693');
```

but not working, i expected one a help, thank for all

Comment: How is it working at the moment? What are you expecting your result to be?

Comment: hi, thank Daryl Gill, i want download file from xooplate to my host, because it very security should be as want try

Answer (score 0):

> **Updated Answer :**

Hey buddy, i checked that site. they put onClick jQuery method on the download button ([widget.js](http://platform.stumbleupon.com/1/widgets.js) line 27) with the post domain security. I tried to [trigger the onClick](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) event but due to domain check security functiion server only allows http://www.stumbleupon.com and http://xooplate.com to post the data using AJAX. So it wouldn't be possible using curl or PHPDOM. Sorry. :) Great Security.

> **Below Solution is not the answer !**

Hi I found a solution using [PHP Simple HTML DOM Library](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm). Just Download it and use the following code

```
<?php
include("simple_html_dom.php");
$html = file_get_html('http://xooplate.com/templates/details/13693-creative-circular-skills-ui-infographic-psd');


foreach($html->find('a[class=btn_green nturl]') as $element) 
       echo $element->href . '<br>';
?>
```

Comment: hi, very thank your answer, i want save file form xooplate to my hosting, link download not working, i need help more.

Comment: @DinhDung : i updated my ans. not possible. they implemented greater security

Comment: thanks for help and share your enthusiasm, xooplate is a system interesting